# Can I have two JavaScript onclick events in one element?

Tags: javascript

Can we put two JavaScript onclick events in one input type button tag?  To call two different functions?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This one works:

`<input type="button" value="test" onclick="alert('hey'); alert('ho');" />`

And this one too:

```
function Hey()
{
    alert('hey');
}

function Ho()
{
    alert('ho');
}
```

.

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="Hey(); Ho();" />
```

So the answer is - yes you can :)
However, I'd recommend to use unobtrusive JavaScript.. mixing js with HTML is just nasty.

Comment: It's not "nasty". It's just not recommended because some users turn off JavaScript and for a couple other reasons. https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 20):

The HTML

```
<a href="#" id="btn">click</a>
```

And the javascript

```
// get a cross-browser function for adding events, place this in [global] or somewhere you can access it
var on = (function(){
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        return function(target, type, listener){
            target.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
        };
    }
    else {
        return function(object, sEvent, fpNotify){
            object.attachEvent("on" + sEvent, fpNotify);
        };
    }
}());

// find the element
var el = document.getElementById("btn");

// add the first listener
on(el, "click", function(){
    alert("foo");
});

// add the second listener
on(el, "click", function(){
    alert("bar");
});
```

This will alert both 'foo' and 'bar' when clicked.

Answer (score 12):

There is no need to have two functions within one element, you need just one that calls the other two!

### HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="my_func()" >click</a>
```

### JavaScript

```
function my_func() {
    my_func_1();
    my_func_2();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can attach a handler which would call as many others as you like:

```
<a href="#blah" id="myLink"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myOtherFunction() {
//do stuff...
}

document.getElementById( 'myLink' ).onclick = function() {
   //do stuff...
   myOtherFunction();
};

</script>
```

Comment: the downside of this method is that the context here will be the global window object and "this" would not work inside myOther.... declaration, this just refers the function and do not attach it to the onclick property of the element, it is worth to explain this. :) Apart from this the answer will work for the case "call 2 functions or 200".

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this as well

```
<a href="#" onclick="one(); two();" >click</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function one(){
        alert('test');
    }

    function two(){
        alert('test2');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

##### The **HTML**

```html
<button type="button" onclick="buttons()">Submit</button>
```

##### **The JavaScript**

```js
function buttons() {
   alert("Part 1");
   button2();
}

function button2() {
   alert("Part 2");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34737259)