# changing the button name when clicked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **bootstrap** button which displays "Show User Information" as the button lable. When user click on the button, i want to change the label to "Display Only Users" and again when user click on "Display Only Users" it has to change the button label to "Show User Information".

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton1">Show User Information</button>
```

js code:

```
  function myFunction() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
         if (elem=="Show User Information") elem.value = "Display Only Users";
        else elem.value = "Show User Information";
}
```

The above js code is not changing the button label when clicked. Any inputs?

Comment: `elem=="Show User Information"` is false

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671174/changing-button-text-onclick

Comment: @a2441918 flag  the question as such

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing button text onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671174/changing-button-text-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

Add value attribute to the button ,

```
value="Show User Information"
```

and retrieve in js using and compare

```
ele.value=="Show User Information"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the text of the button, not the element itself

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1"),
      text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;

  if (text === "Show User Information") 
    elem.innerHTML = "Display Only Users";
  else 
    elem.innerHTML = "Show User Information";
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton1">Show User Information</button>
```