# Change button's text and function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to do the following. I got a button like this:

```
<button class="uk-button uk-position-bottom" onclick="search.start()">Start search</button>
```

The JS part is this:

```
var search = new SiteSearch();
```

Now I'd like to do this:

Once clicked, the label of the button should show `Stop search`. And the called function should be `search.stop()`. If the user clicks `Stop search`, the button should be the `Start search` button again.

How can I do this in an elegant way?

Comment: Is there a stop search, or `search.stop()` method available? Is there any documentation you should have linked to that would help us understand what `SiteSearch()` is? What have you tried, how did it fail? What went wrong? How do you define 'elegant'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have working code snippet for this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function startSearch() {
     console.log('Here your start search procedure');
  }
  
  function stopSearch() {
     console.log('Here your stop search procedure');
  }
  
  $('.search-button').click(function() {
      var buttonSelector = '.search-button';
      
      if($(buttonSelector).hasClass('searching')) {
          $(buttonSelector).removeClass('searching');
          $(buttonSelector).text('Start search');
          stopSearch();
      } else {
          $(buttonSelector).addClass('searching');
          $(buttonSelector).text('Stop search');
          startSearch();
      }
  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="uk-button uk-position-bottom search-button">Start search</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do: add an ID to the button, then query that button in the script and add a click listener to it. The script would keep track of whether or not a search is being done, then call `search.start/stop()` and set the button text accordingly.

```
<button id="search-button" class="uk-button uk-position-bottom">
  Start search
</button>

<script>
  const search = new SiteSearch()
  const searchButton = document.querySelector('#search-button')

  let searching = false

  searchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!searching) {
      search.start()
      searching = true
      searchButton.textContent = 'Stop search'
    } else {
      search.stop()
      searching = false
      searchButton.textContent = 'Start search'
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html:

```
<button id="search-btn" "class="uk-button uk-position-bottom" onclick="toggleSearch()">Start search</button>
```

JS:

```
var searching = false;
function toggleSearch(){
   if(searching){
       search.stop();
       document.getelementbyid("search-btn").innerHTML = "Start search";
   }else{
       search.start();
       document.getelementbyid("search-btn").innerHTML = "Stop search";
   }
   searching = !searching;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily like below:

```js
var $elem = $('.uk-button.uk-position-bottom');
var search = {
  //start function
  start: function(){
    //change the text
    $elem.text('Stop search');
    //change the click function
    $elem.attr('onclick', 'search.stop()');
    console.log('start clicked');
  },
  //stop function
  stop: function(){
    //change the text
    $elem.text('Start search');
    //change the click function
    $elem.attr('onclick', 'search.start()');
    console.log('stop clicked');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="uk-button uk-position-bottom" onclick="search.start()">Start search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this answer is the same as a previus posted question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671201/7387232

with the little add that when the button is clicked the button has to change the onclick propriety maybe with a check

```
object.onclick = function() {
if(search.isRunning()) search.stop();
}
```

and viceversa :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question this will solve your problem:

```
<button class="uk-button uk-position-bottom" data-process="0">Start search</button>

  <script>
                $(".uk-button").click(function () {

                    var $this = $(this);
                    var processStatus = $this.data("process");
                    //var search = new SiteSearch(); 

                    if (processStatus == "0") {
                        //you can trigger start function
                        $this.data("process", "1");
                        $this.text("Stop Search");
                    }
                    else if (processStatus == "1") {
                        //you can trigger stop function
                        $this.data("process", "0");
                        $this.text("Start Search");
                    }

                });
 </script>
```