# How can I change the button‘s text on a click event?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I want to change the text of a button when it‘s cklicked and change it back when it‘s clicked again. How can I do that?

I tried something like that. But I dont know who I can adress to the text because there is no property like eg with color for ion-buttons

Html

```
<button (click)="changeText()" ion-button>Hello</button>
```

TS

```
  public text: string = 'hello';
```

constructor

```
 public changeText(): void {
      if(this.text === 'hello') { 
        this.text = 'rank'
      } else {
        this.text = 'hello'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please show your existing code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing button text onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671174/changing-button-text-onclick)

Comment: Please try to do some research before posting the question. Post your code where you are getting the problem

Comment: Ok sorry for the bad question I posted my existing code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use interpolation, then your button would look like this:

```
<button (click)="changeText()" ion-button>{{text}}</button>
```

Comment: can I do (click)=" text='new text' "?