# Dynamically change button name to execute other function in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to change a button name once it is clicked.There are two function differently Add and Subtract.  first time button name is 'Add' ,when it clicked it should execute add number function and then name dynamically change button name to Subtract and once i clicked to subtract it should execute subtract function and again name of button come to Add which is previous. How can I do this? how to call a different function like add function when button toggle is add and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent {
  buttonNameToggle = true;
  buttonName: 'Add' | 'Subtract' = 'Add';

  onMouseUp() {
    this.buttonName = this.buttonNameToggle ? 'Add' : 'Subtract';
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<button (mouseup)="buttonNameToggle = !buttonNameToggle; onMouseUp()">{{ buttonName }}</button>
```

#### Update: AngularJS

Controller

```js
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);
module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.toggle = true;
});
```

Template

```html
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">
      {{ toggle ? 'Add' : 'Subtract' }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4menk6w3/1/)

#### Update: call different event handlers

Controller

```js
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);
module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.toggle = true;
  
  $scope.add = () => { console.log('add called') };
  $scope.subtract = () => { console.log('subtract called') };
});
```

Template

```html
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle; toggle ? subtract() : add()">
      {{ toggle ? 'Add' : 'Subtract' }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add the event handlers based on the status of the `toggle` variable. If `toggle` is true call `subtract()`, if not call `add()` function.

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/715rt30h/)

Comment: Thanks .It is angular js. But can we please share the java script code also for the same

Comment: AngularJS and Angular are very different versions. What I've shown is Angular. For pure Javascript, it has been already extensively documented. Eg. https://stackoverflow.com/q/10671174/6513921

Comment: yes . I want in Angular js and javascript not in Angular. I did not understand export class Appcomponent which is in angular ,how we can convert this to angular js

Comment: thanks a lot!! @Michael D .Add and Subtract are function name , Right?

Comment: i can toggle the button add to subtract but facing issue with calling function add and subtract both. Please help

Comment: @VarshaAkhade: I've updated the answer to call different event handlers based on the value of `toggle` variable.