# change value of input button inside php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to write a code of following different user, with inserting values from MySQL table

```
<td align="center">
<input type="button" name="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="suivre"> 
</td>
```

I want to know if there's any solution after clicking each time on the button and the value change to following

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing button text onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671174/changing-button-text-onclick)

Comment: but my id change, how put $id into  document.getElementById()

Comment: You don't have to use `getElementById`. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671174/changing-button-text-onclick#comment13844521_10671201) for example.

Comment: it's not working, could you write me a code so I can test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unsuccessful because id attribute cannot start with a digit.
Try the following basic examples based on the javascript examples you received here

Example1 with getElementById

```
<input onclick="change()" type="button" name="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="el_<?php echo $id; ?>" value="suivre"> 
<script>
function change(){
  document.getElementById("el_<?php echo $id; ?>").value="Hello world1";
}
</script>
```

Example2 without id or getElementById

```
<input onclick="change(this)" type="button" name="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="suivre"> 
<script>
function change(el){
  el.value="Hello world2";
}
</script>
```