# Executing two javascript functions at the same time from one button?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
<center>
        <form id="f1">
            <textarea name="textcontent" id="styled" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
                <br>
            <input onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/test.py")' type="button" value="Show" class="blue"/>
                <br><br>
            <div id="qList">
                <img id="loading_image" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
            </div>
        </form>
</center>
```

I want the image as shown in the code to appear when the `Show` button is clicked and the image to be replaced by the content returned by the python file.

I know I can use this script `onclick="$('#loading_image').show();"`, but how can I make them execute together, so that image is replaced by some other content ?

Comment: Call a function that calls both those functions.

Comment: `onclick="$('#loading_image').show();"` that can't be unseen :( One either uses obtrusive javascript or use unobtrusive javascript. You're using both techniques at the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [onclick multiple javascript functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/onclick-multiple-javascript-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it is better to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener), or [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) from jQuery.

Second, all you have to do is have your handler call those two functions:

```
function handler() {
    xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/test.py");
    $('#loading_image').show();
}
```

Then bind as follows:

```
<input id="myInput" type="button" value="Show" class="blue"/>

...

$("#myInput").on("click", handler);
```

Comment: I added this function, but when I open the html page the gif image still appears under the button before clicking it !

Comment: @AnimeshPandey You need to style the image as hidden initially in your HTML (`visibility: hidden`, or `display: none`), otherwise it will show up.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is:

```html
<input type="button" onclick="manyfunctions()" value="Send" />
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And script.js should be like this:

```js
function manyfunctions() {
  somefunctions()
  anotherfunction()
    //List functions to herre
}
```