# HTML DOM Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a drop down menu that, when clicked, successfully changes the image's thumbnail. But, I also need the `<p>` text to change. I looked at W3Schools, and still to no avail. Here is my code.

```
<p id="caption"></p>
<select name="woodType" id="woodType" onChange="changeThumbnail();changeCaption(this);">

<script>
    function changeCaption(selTag) {
        var caption = selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("caption").text = "Wood: " + caption;
    }
</script>
```

The text will NOT change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text` is property of `option` elements not `p`.To set `p` text you should be using `.innerHTML`,

```
function changeCaption(selTag) {
    var caption = selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "Wood: " + caption;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LCruB/)

Comment: This works, it just wont work in my site for some reason! I'm so frustrated.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following :

```
 <script>
     function changeCaption(selTag) {
         var caption = selTag.value;
         document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "Wood: " + caption;
     }
 </script>
```

You should use `innerHTML` property to set or return the text of the `<p>` element.

Comment: Yep, you beat me to it. `.text()` is a jQuery shortcut, not a native JavaScript method

Comment: -1 `.text` sets / returns text of an option . and `p` does not have text property so you should use `innerHTML` .As you good practice you should always mention behavior of you change

Comment: @user3547286 : have you got any error in your js console? However, this issue could occur due to using 2 js function on the same event, so you can try to wrap your functions in one and see if it helps. Also read:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/onclick-multiple-javascript-functions

Comment: no error. could it be because of my divs? maybe I don't have one closed somewhere

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById [returns a reference to a DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById). You can think of [few candidates](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) you can use on the Element object namely [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent), [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) and [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox))

If you read the article [here](http://www.davidtong.me/innerhtml-innertext-textcontent-html-and-text/) and documentation on [developer.mozilla.org](http://developer.mozilla.org) you'll notice that its better use textContent than using innerHTML for your requirement.

In the Mozilla documentation for innerHTML under [security considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML#Security_considerations) it says,

> It is recommended you not use innerHTML when inserting plain text;
>   instead, use node.textContent. This doesn't interpret the passed
>   content as HTML, but instead inserts it as raw text.