# Can I have 2 JavaScript onClick events in a single element?

Tags: javascript, html

Can you put 2 JavaScript onClick events in a single element, this is what I have tried so far, I've tried calling functions but that wouldnt work either.

```
<div class="contactme"><a href="#contactnav" onclick="document.getElementById('download').style.display='none'; document.getElementByID('skype').style.display='none';">Message me!</a></div>
```

Calling functions:

```
function hide(){
document.getElementById('download').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('skype').style.display='none';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contactme"><a href="#contactnav" onclick="hide();">Message me!</a></div>
```

However none of them seem to work.

Comment: Show the HTML for "download" and "skype" elements. Are there errors in the browser's error console?

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Ajey Upon clicking the "Message Me" text it would hide the div 'skype' and also the div 'download'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can do it in pure Javascript. Your HTML doesn't need the `onclick` property at all.

HTML:

```
<div class="contactme"><a href="#contactnav">Message me!</a></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var contact = document.getElementsByClassName("contactme")[0];

contact.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('download').style.display='none';
    document.getElementByID('skype').style.display='none';
}
```

Now you can use `contact.addEventListener` to add any function you want, like this:

```
contact.addEventListener("click", hide);
```

Comment: I am putting the script in <script> tags on my HTML page, would having to add the function be required?

Comment: @KarimVally not required, but recommended

Comment: @KarimVally I provided you a working example, if your code doesn't work tnhen it means the problem is somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ErnestoOsuna/2pjfL5oq/
    Message me!

```
element=document.getElementById('some_id');
element.addEventListener('click',some_func);
element.addEventListener('click',some_func2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your both code is correct but, in first code you typed 'document.getElementByID'.
just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.addEventListener(Event, Function, false);`

```
document.getElementById('ELEMENTID').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // onclick code here
}, false);

document.getElementById('ELEMENTID').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // more code here
}, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

[How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event)

And about your snippet,

```
onclick="hide()"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it logically i.e:

```
<div class="contactme">
<a href="#contactnav" onclick="myfun('one')">Message me!</a>'
</div>
```

Now in javascript do this programatically:

```
function myfun(var execute){

    if(execute=="one"){
    // execute this if it is one
    }
    else(execute=="two"){
    // execute this if it is two
    }

}
```

Now here whenever you call `myfun('one')` it execute your first condition and `myfun('two')` it execute second.