# Run 2 functions with one button Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I use this HTML and JS code, which I downloaded from the web to record audio, but there is a problem because after the page is loaded on the screen immediatelly appears message to allow microphone. It is because of  `window.onload = function init()`in source code record.js. But  I want to show the message after clicking on button.

For this reason I tried to call two functions with this button  - `toggleRecording(button)` and `init()` but there was a problem with "button" element, so it didn't work, but I think it could work if it will be written in good form. Can you show me example how to modify this two functions `init` and  `toggleRecording` to be called by this button? I am new in JS and I don't know how it works exactly.

**index.html**

```
<button type="submit" onclick="toggleRecording()" data-run="0"></button>
```

**record.js**

```
//starts by click on button
  function toggleRecording() {
    var run = parseInt(getAttribute('data-run')); //

      if(run === 1) {
      recorder && recorder.stop();
      recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
        uploadAudioFromBlob(blob);
      });
      __log('Recording is  stopped.');
      button.setAttribute('data-run', 0);

    } 

    else {
      recorder && recorder.clear();
      recorder && recorder.record();
      __log('Speak...');
      button.setAttribute('data-run', 1);
    }
  }

  function __log(e, data) {     
showInfo("\n" + e + " " + (data || ''));  
  }

  var audio_context;
  var recorder;
  function startUserMedia(stream) { 
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream); 
    recorder = new Recorder(input); 
    __log('Systém for recording is available.'); 
  }

  function startRecording(button) {   
    recorder && recorder.clear(); 
    recorder && recorder.record(); 
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Talk...'); 
  }

   window.onload=function init() {
    try { 
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext; 
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;   
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;      
      audio_context = new AudioContext;      
    } catch (e) { 
      alert('This browser do not support audio!');
    }    
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
      __log('No audio was detected: ' + e);
    });
  };
```

**UPDATE:**
Now  this system works in this steps:
1. `function init()` runs immediatelly when page is loaded and after user allows microphone then `startusermedia` function runs
2.after clicking on button runs `toggleRecording(button)` function which starts recording 
3.second click on button runs `toggleRecording` function which stop recording

I want to work this system in this steps if it is possible:
1.first click on button run functions `init` and `startusermedia` and `togglerecording` so recording will starts immediately after clicking
2.second click will call `toggleRecording` function to stop recording

Comment: Did you try `onclick="toggleRecording(); init();"` this way, change order as you wish

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event)

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because `init()` is actually a variable attached to `window.onload`.  Try removing `window.onload=function init()` and replacing it with just `function init()` (so it no longer runs when the page loads), then call:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="init();toggleRecording()" data-run="0"></button>
```

When you're setting up event handlers like that, you don't even need to give the function a name.  Something like `window.onload = function() { ... }` is perfectly valid - they're called [anonymous functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression)

I also noticed some implementation troubles with `toggleRecording()`, so I've done my best to fix those too.  `getAttribute()` needs an element, of course, so we can pass the button using `this`, and receive it in `toggleRecording()` as the `button` variable.

Your full code is now:

```js
//starts by click on button
function toggleRecording(button) {
  var run = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-run')); //

  if (run === 1) {
    recorder && recorder.stop();
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
      uploadAudioFromBlob(blob);
    });
    __log('Recording is  stopped.');
    button.setAttribute('data-run', 0);

  } else {
    recorder && recorder.clear();
    recorder && recorder.record();
    __log('Speak...');
    button.setAttribute('data-run', 1);
  }
}

function __log(e, data) {
  //TODO: Uncomment this, I have it commented so there are no errors in the StackSnippet
  //showInfo("\n" + e + " " + (data || ''));
  console.log(e.data);
}

var audio_context;
var recorder;

function startUserMedia(stream) {
  var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  recorder = new Recorder(input);
  __log('Systém for recording is available.');
}

function startRecording(button) {
  recorder && recorder.clear();
  recorder && recorder.record();
  button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
  __log('Talk...');
}

function init() {
  try {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    audio_context = new AudioContext;
  } catch (e) {
    alert('This browser do not support audio!');
  }
  navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  }, startUserMedia, function(e) {
    __log('No audio was detected: ' + e);
  });
};
```

```html
<button onclick="init(); toggleRecording(this)">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have found that it wouldn't work. Please see my update in question how it should work. Please if you know how to do it please show me example.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `init` function is directly attached to the `window.onload` event and can't be called with the button, to ensure its call in the two events declare it as a global function and then attach it to the onload event like this:

**JavaScript:**

```
//function declaration
init = function init() {
try { 
  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext; 
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;   
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;      
  audio_context = new AudioContext;      
} catch (e) { 
  alert('This browser do not support audio!');
}    
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
  __log('No audio was detected: ' + e);
});
};

//Call
 window.onload = init();
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" onclick="init();toggleRecording()" data-run="0"></button>
```

That should do it.

### EDIT:

In order to achieve what you want, you have to attach the `init()` function to the `window.onload` event and the `toggleRecording()` function to the onclick event of the `run button`, like this:

```
//Call
 window.onload = init();
 document.getElementById("run").onclick = toggleRecording();
```

And give your button the `id="run"`:

```
<button type="submit" id="run" onclick="init();toggleRecording()" data-run="0"></button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have found that it wouldn't work. Please see my update in question how it should work. Please if you know how to do it please show me example.

Comment: @Nikolaus take a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach multiple actions to a button programmatically using `addEventListener` if you wanted to.

So you may have:

```
<button id="test" type="submit" onclick="toggleRecording()" data-run="0"></button>
<script>
   var btn = document.getElementById("test");
   btn.addEventListener("click", init);
   btn.addEventListener("click", toggleRecording);
   // More if wanted.
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have found that it wouldn't work. Please see my update in question how it should work. Please if you know how to do it please show me example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the code work after the Button is pressed, you should remove the `onload` event, because this will make the code work after the page is loaded.

You can create a second function and place it in there, Example:

```
function secondFunction(){
    // Put Code inside here
}
```

In the `toggleRecording(button)` function you can call like:

```
function toggleRecording(button) {
    // .. the existing code
    secondFunction();
}
```

If you want the second called first, place it over your existing code.

You also could to following:

`<button type="submit" onclick="toggleRecording();init();" data-run="0"></button>`

But you still need to remove the `onload` event and wrap it around a function like above.

You also could do following (recommended):

`<button id="record" type="submit" onclick="toggleRecording()" data-run="0"</button>`

Code:

```
var button = document.getElementById( 'record' );

var button.onclick = function(e){
     toggleRecording(e);
     secondFunction();
}
```

Also again.. remove the `onload`event if you don't want to do it when the page has loaded.

The last example selects the button element with the ID `record` (I added it to your `button`-Tag) and adds an `onclick`-Event on it with `onclick = function(){}` which will be called when "onclick" of course.

Last but least: Don't just copy code, try to understand it so you can solve your problems easily by yourself :)

Comment: thanks a lot. I have found that it wouldn't work. Please see my update in question how it should work. Please if you know how to do it please show me example.