# One button for more functions = recording in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this source code to record audio in browser. Record.js calls another scripts that provides recording audio and save it to the server.

**index.html**

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="toggleRecording()" data-run="0"></button>
```

**record.js**

```js
//starts by click on button
     function toggleRecording(button) {
    var run = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-run')); 
    if(run === 1) {
      recorder && recorder.stop();
      recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
        uploadAudioFromBlob(blob);
      });
      __log('Recording is stopped');
      button.setAttribute('data-run', 0);
      
    } 
  
        else {
          recorder && recorder.clear();
          recorder && recorder.record();
          __log('Speak...');
          button.setAttribute('data-run', 1);
        }
      }

      function __log(e, data) {     
    showInfo("\n" + e + " " + (data || ''));  
      }

      var audio_context;
      var recorder;
      function startUserMedia(stream) { 
        var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream); 
        recorder = new Recorder(input); 
        __log('System for recording is available.'); 
      }

      function startRecording(button) {   
        recorder && recorder.clear(); 
        recorder && recorder.record(); 
        button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
        __log('Talk...'); 
      }

       window.onload=function init() {
        try { 
          window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext; 
          navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;   
          window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;      
          audio_context = new AudioContext;      
        } catch (e) { 
          alert('This browser do not support audio!');
        }    
        navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
          __log('No audio was detected: ' + e);
        });
      };
```

Now this recording system works in this steps:

1.`function init()` runs immediatelly when page is loaded and after user allows microphone in message `startusermedia` function runs

2. after clicking on button runs `toggleRecording(button)` function which starts recording audio

3.second click on button runs `toggleRecording` function which stop recording audio.

I want to work this system in this steps if it is possible: 
1. first click on button run functions `init` and `startusermedia` and `togglerecording` so recording will starts immediately after clicking 
2. second click will call `toggleRecording` function to stop recording

I tried to modify `record.js` code, so I added this part to the top of the source code, so by click on button is called function `start_KEMT` in stead of `toggleRecording()`. Start_KEMT was created because I want to run functions in correct order.

**Added part to the record.js**

```js
var recording = false;
var recordButton = document.getElementById('recordButton');

//function which is called by click on button
function start_KEMT() {
   if(!recording)
   {
      init();
      toggleRecording(recordButton);
  }
  toggleRecording(recordButton);
  recording = !recording;
}
```

Also function `init()` was modified, so I change it from: `window.onload = function init()` to function `init()`. So it is called by clicking on button, not automatically by browser. Now it works in this way: After click on button it show message to allow microphone, after allowing message shows that: "'System for recording is available.' (function `startUserMedia` is called).After that recording doesnt start. After second click web browser message is showed again to allow mic. And this error is shown in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Please give me any example how to do it right. I am new in JS. This topic is the same as: [One button to run more functions JavaScript (recording audio in browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687385/one-button-to-run-more-functions-javascript-recording-audio-in-browser)

Comment: var run = parseInt(getAttribute('data-run')); you try to get the attribute data-run, on NOTHING.... this is the problem... you have to get the attribute from the button, like you're doing below in your code...

Comment: var run = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-run')); ..............

Comment: @Julo0sS question was updated. I tried it with "button" element, but it work in the same way and also the same error message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are calling a method on nothing.

`getAttribute('data-run');` should be something like `this.getAttribute('data-run');` or `button.getAttribute('data-run');` depending on the context.

Comment: I modified it to: 
  function toggleRecording(button), {
  var run = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-run')); 
  button.setAttribute('data-run', 0);  
    } but the same error is shown :(

Comment: no it works in the same way as it was without "button", so it doesnt work correctly.

Comment: Where do you initialize your button variable? Is it correctly initialized? If you do console.log(button) what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for something like this

```
var audioContext;
var recorder;
var recording = false;
var initialized = false;

var recordButton = document.getElementById('recordBtn');
recordButton.addEventListener('click', start);

//function which is called by click on button
function start(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!initialized) {
        init();
    }
    toggleRecording(e.target);
}

function init() {
    try {
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        audioContext = new AudioContext();
    } catch (e) {
        alert('This browser do not support audio!');
    }
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    }, startUserMedia, function (e) {
        __log('No audio was detected: ' + e);
    });
    initialized = true;
};



function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    recorder = new Recorder(input);
    __log('System for recording is available.');
};

//starts by click on button
function toggleRecording(button) {
    if (recording) {
        recorder && recorder.stop();
        recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
            alert(blob.size);
        });
        __log('Recording is stopped');
        recording = false;
        button.innerText = "Start";
    } else {
        recorder && recorder.clear();
        recorder && recorder.record();
        __log('Speak...');
        recording = true;
        button.innerText = "Stop";
    }
};

function __log(e, data) {
    console.log("\n" + e + " " + (data || ''));
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yfd3g6g2/1/)

Comment: BTW, you should be accepting answers for previous questions, if they've actually answered your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I used vanilla JavaScript.

```
<button id="audioRecordButton">RECORD</button>
```

Also added feature, if you do not stop recording after 10 seconds, the recording will automatically stop.

```
function recordAudioFromMicrophone()
{
    var audioRecordButton = document.getElementById( "audioRecordButton" );
    var isStartRec = true;
    var mediaRecorder;
    var time;
        
    var run = function(stream)
    {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", getAudio);
        audioRecordButton.addEventListener("click", recordHandler);
    }
    function recordHandler()
    {
        if(isStartRec)
        {
            startRec();
            time = setTimeout(stopRec, 10000);
        }
        else
        {
            stopRec();
            clearTimeout(time);
        }
    }
    function startRec()
    {
        mediaRecorder.start();
        isStartRec = false;
    }
    function stopRec()
    {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        isStartRec = true;
    }
    function getAudio(blob){...}
    
    const enableAudio = { audio: true };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(enableAudio).then(run);
}
```