# How to execute Django uri template tags from within client side Java Script?

Tags: django

When we have a url tag in our java template it executes on a click 
`{% url 'product_details'   pk=soproduct.id %}` and it  it is used inside the hyper link the destination will be full path including domain and path.

```
<a href="{% url 'soproduct_details'   pk=soproduct.id %}">{{ soproduct.id }}</a>
```

and works perfect and generate

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/production/subproduct/details/7/

But if we want to use same template tag inside **client side java script**

```
var destination = {% url 'product_details'   pk=soproduct.id %}
```

there is a problem that the link that will be generated will include the path **but will not include the domain**

> /production/subproduct/details/7/

How this can be resolved?

UPDATE:

This is the script I try to execute it is located in the for loop in the django template .

```
<script>


var currentLocation = window.location.href;

function AddCardToTrello() {
  Trello.addCard({
  url: currentLocation,
  name: "{{ soproduct.product }}",
  due: {{ soproduct.required_date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"  }}
});
}

    function addCardThenGo(url) {
        AddCardToTrello();
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

And right after the script I have my call

```
<a onclick="addCardThenGo({% url 'add_to_production_board' pk=soproduct.id uri=request.build_absolute_uri %})">Add to Trello</a>
```

So script will be repeated in the code as many times as loop goes with new parameters

Comment: The `url` tag will always generate the url relative to the host name. The browser automatically takes the current root of your site to build the absolute uri. Same should happen with Ajax calls. The call should work with the generated relative url.

Comment: I had same understanding, but It just doesn't do it when it is used  inside  java script

Comment: As docs say: "{% url %} Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name) matching a given view and optional parameters...". It hasn't been done by django, it's browser's behavior. Anyway, why do you need the domain part there? If you look into the source of the page you will find out that href part is "production/subproduct/details/7/", without domain.

Comment: Since I try to execute backend method call as well as front end javascript in the same click-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638355/how-to-execute-js-functions-and-django-backend-method-call-in-same-click/38638554?noredirect=1#comment64676922_38638554

Comment: @BorisTheAnimal You mean to say, that url tag is in a separate `.js` file? Or inside `<script>` tag embedded in html template? If it is former, it won't work.

Comment: @Artem Kolontay . Yes, you are right . It is not Django. - So when I click on the link browser takes care of the domain. So the problem when JS tries to execute it nobody takes care of the domain and script crashes.  any idea for a workaround?

Comment: @Rosit Jain  inside <script> tag embedded in html template.
I have  big loop so my java script should be located in the right place in template.

Comment: Could you please, provide the script?

Comment: Can you try this out - `{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{% url  'product_details' pk=soproduct.id %}`? Assuming you're rendering the template using `RequestContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think I got it. If the code you provided is exactly the same you are using, then you forgot about quotes. It should be like this:

```
var destination = "{% url 'product_details'   pk=soproduct.id %}";
```

And after that you can make this:

```
window.location.href = destination;
```

**UPDATE**

Please, try to do this:

```
<a onclick="addCardThenGo('{% url 'add_to_production_board' pk=soproduct.id uri=request.build_absolute_uri %}')">Add to Trello</a>
```