# Keeping style fixed to input until changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code at the moment (following on from earliers question):

```
input[type=submit]:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
  outline: none;
}
```

The problem however, is when I click anywhere else on the screen, the background colour reverts to normal. How can I get it to stay and only change if I click another button?
also a further question, how can I get one particular one to default to a colour when the page loads?
at the moment all the colours are black background until you click one, that turns it yellow and then clicking anywhere else on the page, turns that one back to black

pure JS solutions only please

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the background until it's changed again by another button, use JS to change the `input` background instead of just changing on focus.  Either add an event listener or do it right from the HTML like:

`<input type="submit" onclick="this.style.background='yellow';" />`

Then do something similar for your other elements that you want to change the colors for.  That way the color change will stay until another button changes it.

Comment: I thought this but I already have `onClick={this.getTodaysCommits}` tied here. I can't write to onClick twice can I?

Comment: You could do it by including them both in the same onclick event, like onclick='{this.getTodaysCommits};this.style.background='yellow';"

Comment: so how would that look?

Comment: just edited the comment to include a way to do it, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have a `css` code, that changes the background of button when the button is focused. In order to make a default background of button, you should remove `:focus` selector.

```css
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: blue; 
  /* All buttons will be blue after page loaded */
  outline: none;
}

input[type=submit]:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

In your case, you need to change the `background-color` property using JavaScript.

Here is the working example. We set an `active` class to that button, which was recently clicked and remove `active` class from other buttons. You can make this in another way, but the logic is like so.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');

var resetBackgrounds = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <  buttons.length; ++i)
    buttons[i].className = '';
}

for (var i = 0; i <  buttons.length; ++i) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {
    resetBackgrounds();
    this.className = 'active';
  }
}
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
  background-color: blue;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
}

input[type="button"].active {
  background-color: black; 
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Button1" />
<input type="button" value="Button2" />
<input type="button" value="Button3" />
<input type="button" value="Button4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in straight jquery:

```js
$('input')
  .on('click',function(){
  $('input').css('background','')//reset color
  $(this).css('background','yellow')//set color
})
```

```css
input[type=submit]{
  background-color: inherit;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='submit' />
<input type='submit' />
<input type='submit' />
<input type='submit' />
```

the equivalent in js vanilla:

```js
var inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'))

inputs.forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click', handler))

function handler(e) {
  inputs.forEach(x => x.style.background = 'inherit')
  e.target.style.background = 'yellow'
}
```

```css
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: inherit;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='submit' />
<input type='submit' />
<input type='submit' />
<input type='submit' />
```