# Not able to track downloaded files in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, google-analytics

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function downloadCount(type){
  var ajaxparameter="downloaded="+type;
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  var glurl="logger.jsp";
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  }
  } 
  xmlhttp.open("POST",glurl,true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send(ajaxparameter);
 }
</script>
```

```html
<td>
    <a class="dnld" onclick="function handleDownloadLinks(event) 
     {
       ga('send', 'event', 'Download', 'Click', 'ForwardIC_4.0.war');
     };
                                downloadCount(&quot;ForwardIC_4.0.war&quot;);"

                                              href="https://example.com/pub/infocenter/Forward/Release4.0/ForwardIC_4.0.war">

<img src="images/download.gif" alt="Download" border="0" style="margin-right:3px">Download</a>
 </td>
```

I am trying to track the file names(which are being downloaded by the user) when they click on link.
The page view is being tracked but the download event is not being tracked,i.e. the file name is not being reflected the GA console

Comment: Have you implemented event tracking for the file download ? If yes please provide us with the code so we can help you

Comment: I have attached the code .Kindly let me know if I need to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look I can't detect something wrong but you should carefully follow some patterns described in this post [How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event) . That will decouple the Ajax call from the ga download event. Give it a try

Also the `&quot;` means double quotes("). So it will probably give you an error. Try adding your filename with single quotes (').

Comment: thanks a lot.I will try to check it on test server .

Comment: Cool, test it and if is ok let me know

Comment: I made the changes as you had suggested but still I am not able to register the events .I have updated the code to reflect my changes.