# How do I simultaneously hide a div and redirect to a new HTML page when something is clicked once?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have this code

```
<a href="/#/routeOne" onClick="hide('page1')" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>
```

which in one click is supposed to display a new page, One.cshtml and hide index.cshtml (the current page). However, it takes 2 clicks in order for this to happen as the first click displays One.cshtml *and doesn't* hide index.cshtml and the second click hides finally hides index.cshtml.

Here is the code for the hide function if it helps:

```
   function hide(obj) {
            var el = document.getElementById(obj);
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
```

I'm also having trouble understanding why index.cshtml doesn't disappear automatically when it is redirected to One.cshtml. I feel like I must be doing something incorrectly in general.

Comment: you can run two functions on one click. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onClick="hideandgo('page1')" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>

function hideandgo(obj) {
            var el = document.getElementById(obj);
            el.style.display = 'none';
            window.location.href = /#/routeOne;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing occurs even with this code but thanks for giving it a shot!

Comment: @bobthebuilder4t5 remove href from anchor tag