# Set state and run function on a single onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to set state and run a function on a `onClick` event. How do I accomplish this in React?

I've atttempted to put these two things in [their own function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3910751/1417223), but that give me this warning below.

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

```
editLink(onEditLink, link) {
  this.setState({showContent: false});
  onEditLink(link);
}

render() {
  return (
    <a onClick={this.editLink(this.props.onEditLink, this.props.link)}>Edit</a>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are calling the function right away instead of assigning a new function which will be executed when the element is clicked:

```
editLink(onEditLink, link) {
  this.setState({showContent: false});
  onEditLink(link);
}

render() {
  return (
    <a onClick={() => this.editLink(this.props.onEditLink, this.props.link)}>Edit</a>
  )
}
```

What you want to do is pass a function, which when executed, will call your `this.editLink` function with those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

[`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) accepts a callback function as its second argument, I suggest you utilize that:

```
editLink(onEditLink, link) {
  this.setState({showContent: false}, () => {
     onEditLink(link);
  });
}
```

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function
>   that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is
>   re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for
>   such logic instead.

Comment: Hm, your solution seems very reasonable. But trying it out, I'm still getting that warning message..