# Click menu close outside of menu not working - buttonevent.matches if not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

The dropdown menu which is supposed to close when clicking outside of the menu button is not working. I have had this problem before but the problem re-occurred and can't get to a solution. Help would be appreciated. I am not sure as to why the code doesn't work, so some clarification would be helpful.

```js
let btnn = document.getElementById("btn");
btnn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  dropdown.classList.toggle("visible");
})

window.onclick = function(event){
    if (!event.target.matches('#btn')) {
        let dropd = document.getElementById('dropdown');
        dropd.classList.remove("visible");
    } 
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    background: red;
    height: 10vh;
}

.logo #logo {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 10vh;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-left: 0.8em;
    
}

button#btn {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
}

nav ul {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    text-align: center; 
}

.link {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    background-color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 7vh;
    line-height: 7vh;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

.visible {
    display: block;
}

.fa-bars:before, .fa-navicon:before {
    content: "\f0c9";
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 10vh;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) { 
    
    .fa-bars:before, .fa-navicon:before {
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    /* #dropdown {
        display: block;
    } */

}
  
  @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    .fa-bars:before, .fa-navicon:before {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> -->
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/36947df53d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="logo">
    <p id="logo">Logo</p>
    <button id="btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>
  </div>
   <nav>
     <ul id="dropdown">
       <li><a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="link">Link 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you mean `event.target.matches`?

Comment: yeah, thanks... still no luck though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me restructure your javascript better. It will solve your problem and the code is precise too I think.

```
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", function(event){  
  let dropd = document.querySelector('#dropdown');
  if (!event.target.parentNode.matches('#btn')) {    
    dropd.classList.remove("visible");
  } else {
    dropd.classList.toggle("visible");
  }
});
```

In your previous code, I believe your button click was overridden by the window click. Here, I'm clicking on the body and simply matching the button id. If it matches, then I'm doing the toggle and otherwise, I'm removing the class.

*** I've used parentNode. If you're wondering why I'd used that you can just simply console log to see where the button click happens. You will see that the click is getting the icon inside the button. That is why I took the icon parent to check if the click is happening where I want it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.body.addEventListener('click', fn, true);`. Your js file should be like this maybe

```
let btnn = document.getElementById("btn");
btnn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  dropdown.classList.toggle("visible");
})

document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let dropd = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    dropd.classList.remove("visible");
}, true);
```

Comment: You probably want to add a `.preventDefault()` to the `btn` click

Comment: good that you have mentioned it. thanks.

Comment: does anyone happen to know why window.onclick did not work?

Comment: maybe this should help your queries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393553/window-onclick-functionevent-only-works-for-first-item

Comment: I added prevent default but how to I make the menu links clickable then