# Trigger two Javascript actions with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I have a button that need to trigger a div and a Google Analytics event. I can't get this to work. Right now, the div triggers fine, but the GA event does not trigger.

This is the HTML:

```
<a class="knappmedium knappfeedbackyes" href="#" onclick="showFeedback('yes');ga('send', 'event', 'Feedback', 'Feedback positive', 'PAGEURL');">YES</a>
```

**Edit:
This button will be on multiple pages, with the GA tacking parameters unique for each instance it is used.**

Help would be very much appreciated!

Kind regards,
Pete

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3910736/1747014

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try querySelector ?

```
document.querySelector('.knappmedium.knappfeedbackyes').addEventListener('click', function(){
    showFeedback('yes');
    ga('send', 'event', 'Feedback', 'Feedback positive', 'PAGEURL');
});
```

Comment: This button will be on multiple pages, with the GA tacking parameters unique for each instance it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, verify that:

- You are using google analytics.js instead of gtag.js. You can follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/).
- Verify that you have added correctly analitycs js [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)
- The analitycs.js should be added before the events that you want to call.
- Verify that you have the correct GA api key.

Answer (score 0):

It does work. Check the snippet below.

```js
function showFeedback(){
  console.log('showFeedback');
}

function ga(){
  console.log('ga');
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="showFeedback();ga();">YES</a>
```

Comment: This button will be on multiple pages, with the GA tacking parameters unique for each instance it is used.