# How can i call 2 functions using onClick with Javascripts

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have:

```
one = () => {
   //do something
}
two = () => {
   //do something
}

<div>
   <button onClick={/*this.one, this.two  (it doens't work)*/}>Go</button>
</div>
```

How can i call two functions using just one onClick?

Comment: Why cant you call two functions within a single function?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<div>
   <button onClick={this.one; this.two}>Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.one; this.two` and `"one();two();` don't work

Comment: This question is repeated. Plese, check this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event

Answer (score -1):

[How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event)

```
one = () => {
   //do something
}
two = () => {
   //do something
}

<div>
   <button onclick="one();two();">Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you see a duplicate of a question, please don't answer the question. Instead, please flag the question as a duplicate.