# Press a button and change the color of box elsewhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I'm very new to coding and have learned my very limited knowledge from forums and tutorials online.  I seem to be up against a problem that I cannot for the life of me figure out.

My goal is to press one of three buttons (Leadership, Program, Team) at the top of a grid (the grid lists our services) and have the appropriate grid box change colors.  For example, pressing the Leadership button would turn a grid box blue, Program would turn a grid box yellow, and Team would turn a grid box green.  This means that a grid box might be linked to more than one of the buttons, as our services overlap. So depending on what button is pressed, a single grid box might change to blue, yellow, or green.

I figured out how to do toggle buttons which show the body onclick.  BUT that means A LOT of redundancy. (I would have to do a grid with the appropriately colored boxes for Leadership, another one for Program, and another one for Team). So, I think I'm on the wrong path there.

I've searched toggles, buttons, anchors, event listeners, targets, you name it.  It seems like it all relates to the button itself, not how the button relates to an element on the page.

I am very grateful to anyone who can point me in the right direction!  Thank you!

```js
    function goToAnchor(anchor) {
      var loc = document.location.toString().split('#')[0];
      document.location = loc + '#' + anchor;
      return false;
    }
    var divs = ["Div1", "Div2", "Div3", "Div4"];
        var visibleDivId = null;
        function divVisibility(divId) {
          if(visibleDivId === divId) {
            visibleDivId = null;
          } else {
            visibleDivId = divId;
          }
          hideNonVisibleDivs();
        }
        function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
          var i, divId, div;
          for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divId = divs[i];
            div = document.getElementById(divId);
            if(visibleDivId === divId) {
              div.style.display = "block";
            } else {
              div.style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
```

```css
    .square-grey {
     display: table-cell;
     height: 100px; 
     width: 600px;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     border-radius: 5%;
    /*make it pretty*/
     background: #F5F5F5;
     color: #999999;
     padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
     font: 20px "helvetica"; 
     font-weight: 350;
     box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #999999;
    }
    div.highlit {
      padding: 25px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="buttons">
     <div style="text-align:center">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="#anchor" onclick="divVisibility('Div1');">Enterprise</a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4"> 
    <a href="#anchor" onclick="divVisibility('Div2');">Program</a>
       </div>  
       <div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="#anchor" onclick="divVisibility('Div3');">Team</a>  
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_div">
    <div id="Div1">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="col-sm-3"> 
         <div class="top-buffer">
          <div class="square-grey">
           Strategic Alignment
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"> 
         <div class="top-buffer">
          <div class="square-grey">
          Adaptive Leadership
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"> 
        <div class="top-buffer">
         <div class="square-grey">
          Portfolio Management
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"> 
        <div class="top-buffer">
         <div class="square-grey">
          Cultural Shift
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two</div>
    <div id="Div3" style="display: none;">I'm Div Three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer, you can add IDs to the boxes and pass them to function.

```js
const changeColor = (elements, color) => {
  elements.forEach(el => {
    const element = document.querySelector(el);
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
  })
}
```

```css
.colorbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorbox" id="colorbox1"></div>
<div class="colorbox" id="colorbox2"></div>
<div class="colorbox" id="colorbox3"></div>

<button onclick="changeColor(['#colorbox1', '#colorbox3'], 'tomato')">Change 1 & 3 to tomato</button>

<button onclick="changeColor(['#colorbox1', '#colorbox2'], 'aliceblue')">Change 1 & 2 to aliceblue</button>

<button onclick="changeColor(['#colorbox2', '#colorbox3'], '#ff0000')">Change 2 & 3 to reddest</button>
```

Comment: Thank you!  How would I go about expanding this code?   When I run this on my page and press "Change to tomato," only one of the boxes changes colors.  When I press "Change Tomato" I would like "Strategic Alignment" AND "Adaptive Leadership" to highlight red.  When I press "Change to aliceblue" I would like "Portfolio Management to highlight blue and "strategic management" and "adaptive leadership" to go back to gray.  Maybe there's a tutorial you could point me to?  Thank you so much! https://pliantsolutions.com/testing-2/

Comment: @PSol edited, take a look. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes!  Almost there!  The first click, Change to tomato, works as expected (Colorbox1 and Colorbox3 are highlighted).  But when I click the next button, Change to aliceblue, Colorbox1 and Colorbox 2 are highlighted, but Colorbox 3 is also still highlighted.  I want Colorbox 3 to go back to the original aquamarine.  I tried this: <button onclick="changeColor(['#colorbox1', '#colorbox3'], '#5AEDE3');(['#colorbox2', '#colorbox4'], '#F5F5F5')">Leadership: Change to tomato</button>, but that didn't work.  Is there a way to simplify with a function onoff()?  Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out!                                                                               <button onclick="changeColor(['#colorbox1', '#colorbox3'], '#5AEDE3'); changeColor(['#colorbox2', '#colorbox4'], '#F5F5F5');">Leadership: Change to tomato</button>  In stumbling around SO, I found a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event.  Not knowing much about JS, I'm not sure how to apply it here.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PSol glad that you've figured stuff out!