# Assigning multiple functions to onclick only triggers the last one

Tags: javascript

Using this JavaScript:

```
function test1() { console.log('Test 1'); }
function test2() { console.log('Test 2'); }

const button = document.getElementById('button');  

button.onclick = function() { test1(); }
button.onclick = function() { test2(); }
```

and this HTML

```
<button id="button">RGB</button>
```

When I click on the button, only "Test 2" is displayed in the console.

Why is this the case? Why aren't both functions executed?

Comment: the latest win on assignment.

Comment: You are *overwriting* the `onclick`.

Comment: Closely related (if not duplicate): [How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look how similar those both lines look

```
button.onclick = function() { test1(); }
button.onclick = function() { test2(); }
```

To make it more clear

```js
let a = "foo";
a = "bar";
console.log(a);
```

Just as we've overridden `a`, you're overriding `button.onclick` by assigning multiple times to it.

You'd usually `addEventListener`s nowadays instead of using `onclick`.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() { test1(); })
button.addEventListener('click', function() { test2(); })
```

Comment: button.addEventListener('click', test1 }) is enough

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on the button, only "Test 2" is displayed in the console.

This is because second function is replacing the previous function which was assigned to `onclick`. You can avoid two `onclick` and call `test2` from `test1`

```js
function test1() {
  console.log('Test 1');
  test2();
}

function test2() {
  console.log('Test 2');
}

const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = function() {
  test1();
}
```

```html
<button id="button">RGB</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

When you change `button.onclick` it doesnot combine the previous values and the new value. Instead the previous one is replaced by new one. n

When you assign a variable to a value. The previous value is overwritten by the new one.

If you want to attach multiple functions for single event use `addEventListener`

```js
function test1() { console.log('Test 1'); }
function test2() { console.log('Test 2'); }
const button = document.getElementById('button');  
button.addEventListener('click',test1) ;
button.addEventListener('click',test2)
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```