# How do we make a form send the submitted information to an email

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<form name="submission" onsubmit="return validateForm()" onsubmit="validateForm2()" method="post">
<label for="Insert Name Here" id="form_para">
FULL NAME   
</label><br><br>
<input type="text" name="Insert Name Here" id="forms"><br><br>
<label for="number" id="form_para">
    PHONE NUMBER
</label><br><br>
<input type="number" name="Phone"><br><br>
<label for="email" id="form_para">
    EMAIL ADRESS
</label><br><br>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit1">
</form>
```

The code for the form i made is above. However i am not able to understand how to send the information submitted by a user to an email address. Is there a way i can setup an email address for a webpage and send that email to my own account? Also how to attatch PHP files to a form. Can someone pls show me?
Also can someone tell me how to use two functions using one button?

`<form name="submission" onsubmit="return validateForm()" onsubmit="validateForm2()" method="post">`

The code above is not able to produce the result that i am willing to get. I want to use two functions but i cannot.

Comment: This will help you with combine two functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event

Comment: you can refer to smtp.js and for example https://blog.mailtrap.io/javascript-send-email/