# How to call same onclick function on multiple element?

Tags: javascript

How to call same onclick function on multiple element?
I want to make show text and show div onclick function as a single click.

I want to call a onclick function that opens div and changes backgoundcolor and fontcolor when I click on any of  parts.

Now onclick function only works on first element.
Please help.

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("answer").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("answer").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  var x = document.getElementById("explain");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

<div class="test">
<ul class="example">
<li>This is</li>
<li id="answer" onclick="myFunction()" style="background-color:#444444; color:#444444;">example.
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="explain" style="display:none">
TEST1
</ul>
</div>
<div class="test">
<ul class="example">
<li>This is</li>
<li id="answer" onclick="myFunction()" style="background-color:#444444; color:#444444;">example2.
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="explain" style="display:none">
TEST2
</ul>
</div>
<div class="test">...</div> X Loop
```

Comment: Where else are you trying to use `myFunction` and how is it failing?  Where do you define `myFunction2`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to call both myFunction() and myFunction2() on click of your ``<li>``

Comment: did u tried instead of a "," comma a ";" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event)

Comment: I can't figure out what the author is asking.

Comment: Sorry myFunction2() is my mistake. Now i deleted. I mean <div class=test> is Loop. But now function only works on first div.

Answer (score 1):

Separate function names by semicolon.

```
onclick="myFunction();myFunction2()"
```

Hope this helps.