# require('fs') doesn't work, don't know why console says there's an error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fs

There's also an error where I try to run multiple functions onclick.

```
<img onclick="showMore(); displayArtwork()" id = "charcoalimg" src = "images/charcoal.png" alt="image">
```

Javascript:

```
function displayArtwork(){
var totalimg;

// get total number of images in painting's directory
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir( 'Code/girl', function(error, files) { 
    var totalimg = files.length; // return the number of files
    console.log(totalimg); // print the total number of files
 });
```

Comment: fs is only available in Node, not the browser.

Comment: As @Phix already mentioned, `fs` package is only available in node.js. For multiple functions on `onclick` event see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event/