# How to call more than one function in javascript onclick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

<Button onClick={(e)=>setId(_id); handleDelete()}>Delete

I tried this way, but it gives error.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event) will solve your problem .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you must wrap the content of the arrow function in { }, like this

```
<Button onClick={(e) => {setId(_id); handleDelete()} }>Delete</Button>
```

and don't forget the closing tag for the Button component

I hope that solves your problem.