# Two Javascript Function in an Onclick

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have two function calls in a onclick? I tried doing something like:

```
onclick="function1(); function2();"
```

Doing that it only executes the first function, but not the second. Anyway to have both in the onclick? It code be on the client side or in the code behind in C#.

Thanks!

Comment: that should work, what are you doing in the first function?

Comment: C# and Javascript have nothing to do with eachother.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have two JavaScript onclick events in one element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881307/can-i-have-two-javascript-onclick-events-in-one-element)

Comment: In the example you've given, both functions **will** be called barring the first throwing an exception. Proof: http://jsbin.com/emohix

Comment: Yes you can, and this is a way to do it. If `function2` is not called, then you have an error in `function1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say either `function1` or `function2` is undefined, or `function1` is throwing an exception, or (with respect) you're simply wrong that both of them don't get called. In the normal case, both will be called ([proof](http://jsbin.com/emohix)).

That's not to say it's a good idea. You'd be much better off defining a third function that calls the other two, or even better using DOM2 handlers and doing away with `onclick` entirely.

Answer (score 1):

That should work. You may have an error in `function1()` which causes everything after it to not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine unless you have an error in one of your functions. However, I encourage other developers to have one function that calls both functions, then call it in your onclick event.

```
   function function3()
   {
     function1();
     function2();
   }

   ... onclick="function3();"
```