# Javascript function that prints results from form stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, crud

I have created a project where the user inputs his or her details in a form and it prints out the results. It was working fine on Friday and i was planning to add CRUD function to it where the user could add more details, but when i was going to continue today to my surprise the function suddenly stopped working and i can not figure out why.

I added a few buttons which in the html and styled in css, but i tried to comment out the code i added so i got back to where it was working but that did not work.

Also i am not getting any errors in the console for my JavaScript code.

Here is the html code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CV Prosjekt</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" >
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cv-form">
            <form name="cv" id="cv" autocomplete="off" class="input-fields">
                <h2 class="h2-venstre">Personalia</h2>
                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="navn1" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Navn" value=''><small>Feilmelding</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="adresse" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Adresse" value=''><small>Feilmelding</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="epost" type="text" class="input" placeholder="E-post" value=''><small>Feilmelding</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="mobil" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Mobil" value=''><small>Feilmelding</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="status" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Sivil status" value=''><small>Feilmelding</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                            <input id="født" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Fødselsdato" value=''><small>Feilmelding</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="h2-venstre">Utdanning</h2>
                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="år" type="text" class="input" placeholder="År" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">    
                        <input id="skole" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Skole" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="fag" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Fag" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="leggTil-knapp">
                        <button type="submit" id="leggTil" class="leggTil">Legg til</button>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
                <h2 class="h2-venstre">Yrkeserfaring</h2>
                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="dato1" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Dato" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="arbeidsgiver" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Arbeidsgiver" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="stillingstittel" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Stillingstittel" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="kompetanse">
                        <textarea rows="5" id="beskrivelse" placeholder="Beskrivelse" value=''></textarea>
                    </div>-->
                    <!--<div class="leggTil-knapp">
                        <button type="submit" id="leggTil" class="leggTil">Legg til</button>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
                <h2 class="h2-venstre">Kurs/etterutdannelse</h2>
                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="dato2" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Dato" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="sted" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Sted" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="navn2" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Navn" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="leggTil-knapp">
                        <button type="submit" id="leggTil" class="leggTil">Legg til</button>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
                <h2 class="h2-venstre">Andre opplysninger</h2>
                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="språk" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Språk" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="sertifikat" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Sertifikat" value=''>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input id="interesser" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Interesser" value=''>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="h2-venstre">Nøkkelkompetanse</h2>
                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <div class="kompetanse">
                        <textarea rows="5" id="kompetanse" placeholder="Kompetanse" value='Kompetanse'></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="checkInputs();" onclick="printetekst();" id="openBtn" class="custom">Lagre cv</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-right">
        <div class="position">
            <div id="popup" class="Resultater-bakgrunn">
                <div class="header-høyre">
                    <h1 class="h1-høyre">Din CV</h1>
                    <button id="closeBtn" class="close">&#10006;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="Resultater">
                    <h3 class="høyre-resultat-topp">Personalia</h3>
                    <table class="tables">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Navn</th>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="1"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Adresse</th>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="2"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>E-post</th>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="3"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Mobil</th>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="4"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sivil status</th>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="5"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fødselsdato</th>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="6"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h3 class="høyre-resultat">Nøkkelkompetanse</h3>
                    <table class="kompetanse-table">
                        <tr class="kompetanse-td">
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="7"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h3 class="høyre-resultat">Utdanning</h3>
                    <table class="tables2">
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="8"></p></td>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="9"></p></td>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="10"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h3 class="høyre-resultat">Yrkeserfaring</h3>
                    <table class="tables2">
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="11"></p></td>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="12"></p></td>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="13"></p></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                    <table class="tables2">
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="14"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h3 class="høyre-resultat">Kurs/etterutdannelse</h3>
                    <table class="tables2">
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="15"></p></td>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="16"></p></td>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="17"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h3 class="høyre-resultat">Andre opplysninger</h3>
                    <table class="tables">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Språk</th>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="18"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sertifikat</th>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="19"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Interesser</th>
                            <td><p class="p-resultater" id="20"></p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript code below

```
/* kode for skjema */

const Cv = document.getElementById(cv);
const Navn = document.getElementById(navn1);
const Adresse = document.getElementById(adresse);
const Epost = document.getElementById(epost);
const Mobil = document.getElementById(mobil);

cv.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});

function checkInputs() {
    const navnValue = navn1.value.trim();
    const adresseValue = adresse.value.trim();
    const epostValue = epost.value.trim();
    const mobilValue = mobil.value.trim();

    if (navnValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(navn1, 'Navn kan ikke være tomt');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(navn1);
    }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');

    small.innerText = message;
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}


/* Kode for popup boks */
var popup = document.getElementById('popup');

var btn = document.getElementById('openBtn');

var btn = document.getElementById('closeBtn');

openBtn.addEventListener('click', åpneBoks);

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', lukkeBoks);

function åpneBoks() {
    popup.style.display = 'block';
}

function lukkeBoks() {
    popup.style.display = 'none';
}

function printetekst() {
    document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = document.cv.navn1.value;
    document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = document.cv.adresse.value;
    document.getElementById('3').innerHTML = document.cv.epost.value;
    document.getElementById('4').innerHTML = document.cv.mobil.value;
    document.getElementById('5').innerHTML = document.cv.status.value;
    document.getElementById('6').innerHTML = document.cv.født.value;
    document.getElementById('7').innerHTML = document.cv.kompetanse.value;
    document.getElementById('8').innerHTML = document.cv.år.value;
    document.getElementById('9').innerHTML = document.cv.skole.value;
    document.getElementById('10').innerHTML = document.cv.fag.value;
    document.getElementById('11').innerHTML = document.cv.dato1.value;
    document.getElementById('12').innerHTML = document.cv.arbeidsgiver.value;
    document.getElementById('13').innerHTML = document.cv.stillingstittel.value;
    document.getElementById('14').innerHTML = document.cv.beskrivelse.value;
    document.getElementById('15').innerHTML = document.cv.dato2.value;
    document.getElementById('16').innerHTML = document.cv.sted.value;
    document.getElementById('17').innerHTML = document.cv.navn2.value;
    document.getElementById('18').innerHTML = document.cv.språk.value;
    document.getElementById('19').innerHTML = document.cv.sertifikat.value;
    document.getElementById('20').innerHTML = document.cv.interesser.value;
}
```

The code that is commented out in the html is the code added, before that it was working. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Problem could be `e.preventDefault();` on the form.

Comment: @wazz But if i dont have it the page page will reload automaticly when i try to submit the form, any other way to prevent this? Also it was working with the prevent default before. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: ok. i didn't look at everything. i guess you don't want that. :\

Comment: if you can, plz strip out all the html that does not affect the problem. leave the js and anything that really might be involved in the answer.

Comment: What do you mean with "stopped working"; does it generate an error? Doesn't it execute at all but gives no error? Something else? In the meantime, as a side note, you should have only one submit button for each form while yours has four (including the ones you commented out).

Comment: I found that there is unnecessary opened tag for `table` after `id="13"` please check that (which gives close tag not matched in editor)

Comment: @secan I mean it stopped executing, the input does not get printed on the page anymore which it was before i added the extra buttons, should i use another type off buttons for the purpose of creating add more buttons?

Comment: @theaspirator, can you see any error in the console?

Comment: @secan No there is no errors

Comment: @Codenewbie It still has the same problem, but it was good you noticed that. Thank you, i appreciate it.

Comment: @wazz I cant strip the html because all of it are related to the form, which is supposed to print the text.

Comment: @theaspirator there are multiple onclicks for the button `onclick="checkInputs();" onclick="printetekst();"` this might be the issue

Comment: @Codenewbie You solved the problem, thank you so much. Could you make your answer in a  separate comment so i can mark it solved?

Comment: hey @theaspirator glad you understood it :) no worries ... happy coding

Comment: Thank you again @Codenewbie If you have time answer the question separate, that way i can give you the credit for solving the problem.

Comment: @theaspirator i would suggest you to look at this Q for checking multiple conditions on button click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881307/can-i-have-two-javascript-onclick-events-in-one-element)

Comment: @CodenewbieThank you, i will check it out.