# I want to call two functions from one onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

How can I call two functions from one onclick event? I want to select an object randomly from and array & begin a countdown timer from the same click.

**JavaScript**
Two functions:

```
function GetValue() 
{
    var myarray = new Array("item1", "item2", "item3");     
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    document.getElementById("class1").innerHTML=random;
}

function startTimer()
{
    var timeleft = 10;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
        if(timeleft <=0){
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "That's the ball game!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft;
    }
      timeleft -= 1;
    }, 1000);
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Click" onclick="GetValue();startTimer();" />
<p id="class1">  </p>

<div id="countdown"> </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have two JavaScript onclick events in one element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881307/can-i-have-two-javascript-onclick-events-in-one-element) `onclick="Hey(); Ho();"`

Comment: Yes it does, but only one function gets recognized on the click event. Sorry i didn't explain that in my post.

Comment: @talfreds That's what he does.

Comment: You're missing the `}` at the end of the second function. Aren't you getting errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: You should get a syntax error when the JS loads, and when you click on the button it should say that the function doesn't exist.

Comment: @Barmar i didn't think to check the console to see the error. The missing } was the fix. Thank you.

Comment: What? Isn't the console the first place you check when debugging a JavaScript problem? How else do you debug?

Comment: Extremely novice with JavaScript & web development as a whole. I am still learning.