# How do I add another onclick function after the vote function?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I need to add another onclick function name changeColor() after vote function. How do I do this? I tried like follwing. It doesn't work.

```
 <button  class="ratingButton" th:attr="onclick=|vote('${listAnswer.answer_id}','+1')|" onclick="changeColor()"><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x"></i>UpVote</button><br><br>
```

Comment: Why not write a wrapper function and inside that call these functions which you want to call, and use that function here ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881307/can-i-have-two-javascript-onclick-events-in-one-element

Comment: This question has nothing to do with CSS.